# Kubernetes ConfigMap mounting a single file with underscore in the file path creates a directory

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I followed an answer from [Kubernetes, VolumeMounts a file, not a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491603/kubernetes-volumemounts-a-file-not-a-directory/53503986#53503986) on how to mount a single file as a `ConfigMap` and it has been working as expected. Then the other day I added a new file, which had an underscore in the file name and instead of the single file being mounted, it was mounted as a directory. In the YAML for my `Deployment` below, the file is named `static_files.conf`.

```yaml
  {"kind"=>"Deployment",
   "spec"=>
    {"replicas"=>1,
     "selector"=>{"matchLabels"=>{"app"=>"app", "tier"=>"app"}},
     "strategy"=>{"type"=>"RollingUpdate", "rollingUpdate"=>{"maxSurge"=>"25%", "maxUnavailable"=>"25%"}},
     "template"=>
      {"spec"=>
        {"volumes"=>[{"name"=>"static-files-conf-config", "configMap"=>{"name"=>"static-files-conf-config", "defaultMode"=>493}}],
         "containers"=>
          [{"args"=>["yarn", "start"],
            "name"=>"app",
            "image"=>"my-image",
            "ports"=>[{"protocol"=>"TCP", "containerPort"=>4000}],
            "resources"=>{"limits"=>{"cpu"=>"1000m", "memory"=>"1Gi"}, "requests"=>{"cpu"=>"100m", "memory"=>"100Mi"}},
            "volumeMounts"=>[{"name"=>"static-files-conf-config", "subPath"=>"static_files.conf", "mountPath"=>"/static_files.conf"}],
            "imagePullPolicy"=>"Always"}]},
       "metadata"=>{"labels"=>{"app"=>"app", "tier"=>"app"}}},
     "revisionHistoryLimit"=>3},
   "metadata"=>
    {"name"=>"app"},
   "apiVersion"=>"apps/v1beta2"},
```

If I do `ls -al` on the pod, I see that that `static_files.conf` is a directory.

```
$ ls -al
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root             6 Aug 30 19:49 static_files.conf
```

Why does a file with an underscore in the file path cause this behavior? If I change the file path to be a hyphen, everything works as expected.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak 1.17. Using EKS